# Cannot add field to the field group of the form

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am using:

Application release: Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations, Enterprise edition (July 2017)

Platform release: Update 15 (7.0.4841.41251)

I have a form which is in model A. Currently i'm working in model B. That form has header and lines. Line tab page has a LineGrid which displays fields which are included in Overview field group. I've created a table's(which is datasource of that form) extension, there new field was created and placed to the same Overview field group. Then i've created form's extension and there in LineGrid i see my new field. Although that field is not displayed on form when i run AX.

I cannot place a new field near the LineGrid because i need that field in lines.

What i've tried:

1) Refresh models, then build project.

2) Created new project in model A and included there that form and tried to Refresh models and Build that project(hoping that the form would restore/refresh somehow).

3) Restore form.

4) Synchronize project.

5) Model build.

[image]

On the screenshot from above you can see form's design with that LineGrid in which i need to include my new field.

Comment: Have you tried a full compile?

Comment: Ok, i did a full build of all models and it solved the issue (it's strange that i've already built the required model and all referenced models - and it didn't help).